# How to use Webpack for Just Transpiling not for Bundling

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

can I just use Webpack to transpile code from Src folder to build folder
I don't want to do module bundler just transpiling of code while maintain folder structure in Src Folder

```
 src
   - component (folder)
   - utils . (folder)
     index.js 

 build
    - component (folder)
    - utils . (folder)
      index.js
```

Comment: You most likely want to use [Babel directly for this](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli.html).

Comment: you cant, just use babel-cli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if you can use WebPack, but babel comes with a CLI `babel-cli` which can transpile your scripts.

First, install the CLI.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

Now you can use `babel` on the command line to transpile your files. The example is taken from [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli.html)

This will transpile everything below `src/**` and put the result into `lib/`

```
babel src --out-dir lib
```

`babel-cli` will read your `.babelrc` file and transpile accordingly. You could even add the `--watch` flag, which will scan your sources and continuously transpile all files that have changed.

Comment: @foobarbaz here to help.